# How to create a TXML Document using MSXML 6.0 in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, msxml, msxml6

MSXML 6.0 didn't exist when Delphi 7 was released. Is it possible to configure Delphi's TXML Document to use MSXML 6.0 instead of the older versions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the below code to a unit name uMSXMLVersion or your name of choice and add it to your projects uses

```
{----------------------------------------------------------------------------    
  Set Delphi's XMLDocument to use MSXML v6.0

  Usage:  Include unit in project "uses"-list and Delphi will automatically use
          MSXML v6.0 for TXmlDocument.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------}
unit uMSXMLVersion;

interface

implementation

uses ActiveX, MSXML, MSXMLDOM;

function CreateDOMDocumentEx: IXMLDOMDocument;
const
  CLASS_DOMDocument60: TGUID = '{88D96A05-F192-11D4-A65F-0040963251E5}';
begin
  Result := nil;
  if CoCreateInstance(CLASS_DOMDocument60, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or
    CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IXMLDOMDocument, Result) <> S_OK then
  Result := CreateDOMDocument; //call the default implementation
end;

initialization
  MSXMLDOMDocumentCreate := CreateDOMDocumentEx;

end.
```

Comment: Nice trick to reassign a function. I didn't know you could this dynamic language trick in Delphi. Even better than this is that the guys that created the legacy code I'm working on also didn't know the trick :-)

Comment: [Fatal Error] uMSXMLVersion.pas(13): File not found: 'MSXML.dcu' in Delphi 7 Personal Edition. What am I missing?

Answer (score 9):

The `msxmldom.pas` unit exposes a public `MSXMLDOMDocumentCreate` hook that you can assign a custom handler to, eg:

```
uses
  ..., msxmldom;

const
  CLASS_DOMDocument60: TGUID = '{88D96A05-F192-11D4-A65F-0040963251E5}';

function CreateMSXML6Document: IXMLDOMDocument;
var
  Disp: IDispatch;
begin
  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLASS_DOMDocument60, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER or CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, IDispatch, Disp));
  Result := Disp as IXMLDOMDocument;
  if not Assigned(Result) then
    raise DOMException.Create('MSXML 6.0 Not Installed');
end;

initialization
  msxmldom.MSXMLDOMDocumentCreate := CreateMSXML6Document;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I really think your code is little better than the one from Fritz Deelman, but he answered before.