# How does Delphi's TXMLDocument decide which MS XML version (3.0, 6.0 or even 4.0) to use?

Tags: delphi, msxml, delphi-6, msxml4

I have a program written in Delphi 6 that uses `TXMLDocument`, and during runtime it uses the MS XML 3.0 parser. But this program reports a `The specified module could not be found` error on one computer, and [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/lv-lv/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) reports that the program is trying to access MS XML 4.0 modules and registry keys. This 4.0 installation is incomplete/corrupted and that is why the access fails with `The specified module could not be found`.

**So, the core issue is some mechanism/decision algorithm that diverts `TXMLDocument` from using the standard MS XML 3.0 or MS XML 6.0 versions that are on all the current Windows 10 machine, and that presses `TXMLDocument` to use MS XML 4.0 version. What is this decision mechanism in `TXMLDocument` and how to correct it?**

Of course, I can find, download, and install MS XML 4.0 on the client computer, but this seems to not be the correct solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no secret magic here. It is well known what mechanism is used. You can see the source code for yourself in Delphi's `msxmldom.pas` file.

When `TXMLDocument` uses the MSXML `DOMVendor` on Windows, it simply calls `CoCreateInstance()` in a loop to attempt to instantiate a hard coded list of different versions of MSXML's `IXMLDOMDocument` COM object, in decreasing order of version, until one version finally succeeds, or they all fail.

MSXML 6.0 did not exist yet when Delphi 6 was released, so it is not a version that is attempted. And you said MSXML 4.0 is broken on your customer's system. So it makes sense why MSXML 3.0 ends up being used instead.

Have a look at the following question for how to make `TXMLDocument` use MSXML 6.0 in such an old Delphi version:

[How to create a TXML Document using MSXML 6.0 in Delphi 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7365875/)